# Unable to complete execution of sqlldr command in C# using cmd.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-loader

I am trying to execute *sqlldr* command in C# code(scheduler) by calling it in cmd.exe. I am executing a command to ***INSERT*** records in one of the table of ORACLE 10g database. But the output I am getting from command execution is incomplete and it is given as follows,

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Nov 6 16:23:22 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
```

Below mentioned coding, I have done to execute SQL loader command.

```
string strCommand = "sqlldr userid=Username/Password@DBNAME, control=xyz.ctl, log=pqr.log";

            objProcStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + strCommand);
            //objProcStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            objProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            objProcStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            objProcStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            objProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            objProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            objProcess.StartInfo = objProcStartInfo;

            if (!objProcess.Start())
            {
                ErrorLog.LogError("Scheduler Info.", "Due to some technical reason the process of SQL loader could not started.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the output into a string
                string strResult = objProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the command output.
                Console.WriteLine(strResult);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strResult))
                    ErrorLog.LogError("Scheduler Info.", "Output of SQL loader command :- " + strResult);
            }
```

If anyone has done this, kindly provide suggestion/solution.

Comment: is sqlldr in the local folder? try showing the window and checking what the error is - you are only capturing output, not the errors

Comment: When you run that command directly does it work? Does the log file say anything?

Comment: What happens if UseShellExecute and CreateNoWindow are both true?

Comment: @BugFinder : Yes..  sqlldr is in bin folder of asp.net project folder. I have written this code in try catch block and its not throwing any error. I checked log file twice and I didn't found any error in log file.

Comment: @Nick : I am sorry I didn't got your question 'run command directly..' Exactly what you want to ask? Please can you elaborate your question??

Comment: @tofutim : When I turned flag value of U Useshellexecute property to true, application threw  'standard output' related error.

Comment: Are you sure you need commas in your command string? They look **very** suspicious.

Comment: Good catch @nvoigt - no commas in the FAQ = http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ

Comment: I mean remote on to your web server, open up a command prompt,change to the asp.net bin folder using `cd` then paste that in and run it `sqlldr userid=Username/Password@DBNAME, control=xyz.ctl, log=pqr.log`. Can't  you find anything in the log at all? I would expect something saying that it started at least. I suspect that your asp.net identity doesn't have rights to the import file or log file

Comment: @nvoigt : I have already used this sql loader syntax in .bat file and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you try your bat file on the web server? Under the same user as the web server application pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the main problem. When I cross checked the table columns of database with columns mentioned. Ctl file, I found the mismatch in columns sequence. With corrected the column sequence when I  executed the *sqlldr* command. It executed swiftly.

Comment: and the sqlloader syntax in the batch file that was working fine? was it different in some way?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Yes.. the sql loader syntax worked absolutely fine.